# Exposing class method with default parameter using Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to expose a class with a method having default values for some of the parameters. Consider the following code snippet:

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

class XYZ{
    public:
        List A;
    
    XYZ(List A_) {
        A = A_;
    }

    void show_elem(const int j = 0) {
        Rcpp::print(A[j]);
    }

    void print_elem(const int j) {
        Rcpp::print(A[j]);
    }
};


// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test_show_elem(List A) {
  
  XYZ xyz(A);
  
  xyz.show_elem();
}

RCPP_MODULE(test_xyz) {
      class_<XYZ>("XYZ")
      .constructor<List>()
      .field("A", &XYZ::A)
      .method("print_elem", &XYZ::print_elem)
      .method("show_elem", &XYZ::show_elem)
      ;
};

RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(XYZ);

/*** R
x = list("w","a", 4)
xyz = new(XYZ, x)
xyz$print_elem(1)
test_show_elem(x)
xyz$show_elem()
*/
```

The output is:

```
> xyz$print_elem(1)
[1] "a"

> test_show_elem(x)
[1] "w"

> xyz$show_elem()
Error in xyz$show_elem() : could not find valid method
```

This shows that `show_elem()` works fine from within C++, but is not recognized by R.
It seems that a class method with a default parameter is not properly exposed to R. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It works once you

- change the signature to not have default value: `void show_elem(const int j)`
- call with a value i.e. `xyz$show_elem(2)`

Adjusted code below:

```
class XYZ{
public:
  List A;

    XYZ(List A_) {
        A = A_;
    }

    void show_elem(const int j) {
        Rcpp::print(A[j]);
    }

    void print_elem(const int j) {
        Rcpp::print(A[j]);
    }
};

RCPP_MODULE(test_xyz) {
      class_<XYZ>("XYZ")
      .constructor<List>()
      .field("A", &XYZ::A)
      .method("print_elem", &XYZ::print_elem)
      .method("show_elem", &XYZ::show_elem)
        ;

};

RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(XYZ)

/*** R
x = list("w","a", 4)
xyz = new(XYZ, x)
xyz$print_elem(1)
xyz$show_elem(2)
*/
```

*Edit* I took another look at our [existing Rcpp Modules documentation](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-modules.pdf) and you cannot have a default argument for a `methods` element. You can have default arguments for free functions though.

Comment: Thanks. But the point of the question was to have methods with default parameters exposed, with their default parameter functionality intact. Should I interpret your answer as this is not being possible at the moment? (In your solution, `show_elem()` has now turned into `print_elem()`.)

Comment: I do not recall from the top of my head. I recommend you [read the corresponding vignette](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-modules.pdf) and/or look at existing code.  Rcpp Modules is very clever in what it does, it does not claim to bring every possible C++ feature to R.